# Docker system prune: only current directory

Tags: docker

I'm working on 2 projects that both use Docker, in separate directories.

In the 2nd project, for a new local build, the first command given (of a series of commands) is the following:
`docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q) && docker system prune -a -f --volumes`

However, as a side effect, this kills the containers in the 1st project, also destroying the databases associated with it as well.

This is annoying because I have to constantly rebuild and re-seed the database in the 1st project.

How can I edit the first command such that it only effects the project in the current directory?

Note that this project is also using docker-compose, which I know is good at noting the current directory, so maybe we could make use of docker-compose instead.

The full list of commands given for a new local build are:

1. `docker container stop $(docker container ls -a -q) && docker system prune -a -f --volumes`
2. `docker stack rm up`
3. `docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml build`
4. `docker stack deploy up --compose-file docker-compose.local.yml`

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

-Michael

Comment: Why are you mixing docker and docker-compose commands?

Comment: I don't know, I'm still a newbie with Docker and I didn't put together the commands, a developer that's no longer on the project did. But I'm hoping I can improve the command list. Maybe it has something to do with docker stack? I'm hoping that this list can be edited/refined though.

Comment: You should be able to run `docker-compose up -d --build` without doing any of your other manual steps.  If a container for the current project doesn't exist in the updated `docker-compose.yml` file, Compose will stop and delete it on its own.